# Calling `Main` method of a console application from a form application (by a button click event)

Tags: c#, winforms

**How can I access and run a console application from a windows form**, which is part of the same project. I have a windows form and a console application. I think that I can publish the console application and then use `Process.Start(path to console app)` but this is not what I want. I want to access and use the `Main` method of the console application in my form project. This method would run at a click on a button.

This gives the following error.

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console 
>   or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.

```
private void buttonApplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Ch15Extra_2.Program.Main();
}
```

Here are the methods.

ConsoleApp:

```
namespace Ch15Extra_2
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Here the app is running");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Form1:

```
private void buttonApplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expect to happen. You say you don't want to start the console application as a stand-alone process, but if you invoke the method as-is, then obviously it won't work because you're not in a console application. How would you expect `Console.ReadKey()` to behave in a WinForms app?

Comment: @Tudor I would suppose that Console.ReadKey() woldn't do much on a form. OK, then is it not possible for the form app to call the console app opening a another process, which would come from the main method of the console app being called.

Comment: @Tudor When I wrote form app I ment form control(a button)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to run your console app without WinForms app, and sometimes you want to execute some console code without running a console app, I have a suggestion for you:

You can divide your solution into three parts.

1. WinForms part
2. Console part
3. Dll library.

Link a dll to first and to the second projects.

Then if you need to run shared code from WinFomrs app, you can do:

```
private void buttonApplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var shared = new SharedClass();
    shared.Run();
}
```

`SharedClass` will be implemented in the third project.
You can call it from console app too.

---

*upd*

Project 1 : ClassLibrary.

```
public class SharedClass
{
    public int DoLogic(int x)
    {
        return x*x;
    }
}
```

Proj 2. WinForms. Has a Reference to Project 1

using Shared;

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var shared = new SharedClass();
            textBox.Text = shared.DoLogic(10).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

proj 3. Console App

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here the app is running");
            var shared = new Shared.SharedClass();
            Console.WriteLine(shared.DoLogic(10));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

I've just checked - it works.

Comment: beat me to it by 1 minute...+1 for coming up with the same answer :)

Comment: Is it not possible to run a console app from a form? When I use a classLibrary there is the same error "InvalidOperationException was unhandled Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read."                                                       I can use the code System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path-to-exeFile) but I just wanted to have say a library or a code that would launch the console app when I press a button on a form.

Comment: If you use WinForms - why do you use Console.Read?

Comment: You can run a console or any other app from your application. You can use Process.Start for it. But, if you want to call a method from it - you just use it as a library.

Comment: Process.Start works when it is referring to the published console app pathname. But if I try to run the console app from a library or just the console project it gives the same error:InvalidOperationException was unhandled Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.

Comment: @AntonSizikov This is not working even though the dll is refrenced, I can run the shared class Console app from my console project, but not the forms project.?

Comment: What is your goal? To show the black window or to run useful code? If first - use process.run. But you can't interact with Console all directly.  if second - exctact useful code to dll (and don't use Console.Read method. Why do you need it?

Comment: I've updated my answer. That was my idea. But, if you want to implement an interaction betwen Console and WinForms app - you have to do more complicated tricks.